# hibernate criteria group-wise maximum

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I am trying to achieve the group wise maximum for a date, but even with the log showing the correct query, i get the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException : java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

This the smallest portion of code generating the cast exception:

```
DetachedCriteria maxLogin= DetachedCriteria.forClass(UsersSessions.class,"du");
maxLogin.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.max("du.login").as("login")));

Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(UsersSessions.class,"u");
crit.add(Subqueries.eq("u.login", maxLogin));
```

This is the sql equivalent of what i am trying to do with my full code:

```
SELECT *
FROM   UsersSessions u
WHERE  u.login=(SELECT MAX(du.login)
              FROM UsersSessions ud
              WHERE ud.fkUser = u.fkUser);
```

This would be even better:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
FROM UsersSessions 
[WHERE conditions]
ORDER BY login  DESC) u
GROUP BY u.fkUser
```

But idk how to do a subquery in the `from` part like that...

Edit: OK, just tried casting `maxLogin` to Date but i am getting same exception.

Edit: i just tried this

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(UsersSessions.class,"u");
crit.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.max("u.login").as("login")));
Timestamp max=(Timestamp)crit.uniqueResult();
```

And it worked.

Leaving me with even less places to look at... cero at the moment.
Any ideas of whats causing the cast excepton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working...

So apparently, the `eq` function takes the string as a value of comparition.

```
Subqueries.eq("u.login", maxLogin);
```

This is the one that compares a propertie against the subquery:

```
Subqueries.propertiesEq(new String[]{"u.login"},maxValidacion);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `crit.add(Subqueries.eq("u.login", maxLogin));` maxLogin is type of Date? if not, try convert it to java.lang.Date type.

Comment: Its a date type in the database table, mapping and corresponding class, i can run the query directly in the workbench and it works, but i will try your suggestion in the morning.

Comment: Wait, how do u even cast a detached criteria?
and why would the criteria return a date and the detached of the very same field return a string?